Sales Enablement not showing up
I am trying to test out Enablement Lite, but when I go to setup and type in "Enable" nothing comes up. I went into my "company information" and confirmed we have Unlimited Edition. I also tried going into "Permission Set Licenses" under "Company Information" through Setup, and I added myself to the "Sales Cloud Unlimited" permission set license, but still can't see "Enablement Settings" through Setup.

Have you tried searching "enable" in Quick Find in Setup?

Yes I have I get "No matching items found".

Is your user's profile is System Administrator?

Yes I have role: Administrator, Profile: System Administrator
